# Assembly Function adding strFrom to the end of StrTo

Tags: c, assembly, arm, armv7

This is my assembly code that I'm using currently but I'm only getting the initial string I've tried altering the code but I've been unable to get the correct answer:

```
.global stringCat

.text

stringCat:

stringCat_loop:
LDRB R2, [R1], #1
STRB R2, [R0], #1
CMP R2, #0
BNE stringCat_loop
BX LR
```

This is the C code the functions are called from:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

extern void stringCat(char* strFrom, char* strTo);

int main(void) {
char test3[20] = "ijkl";
char test4[44] = "mnop"
stringCat(test3, test4);

printf("Question 2, stringCat: Correct answer = mnopijkl\n");
printf("Question 2, stringCat: student answer = %s\n\n", test4);

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[My current outputs using my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lxx9I.jpg)

Comment: You need to find the null byte at the end of the first string, and start copying to there.

Comment: You implemented `strcpy()`, not `strcat()`.

Comment: It looks like it should be `stringCat(char* strTo, char* strFrom);`, not `stringCat(char* strFrom, char* strTo);` (after you've found the `\0` in `strTo`)

Answer (score 2):

```
stringCat_loop:
LDRB R2, [R1], #1
STRB R2, [R0], #1
CMP R2, #0
BNE stringCat_loop
BX LR
```

In your code, `R0 == test3`, and `R1 == test4` - and at the end of your function, we want to have concatenated `test3` to `test4` - i.e. `R0` after `R1` (which incidentally is the opposite ordering of the parameters in `strcat`).

**But** in your loop - you are essentially doing `strcpy(R0, R1)` - you iterate over each byte in `R1` until you reach a null byte, and copy each byte into `R0`.

---

What you should do instead is:

1. Find the end of `R1` to start appending to it:

   ```
    loop_r1:
    LDRB R2, [R1], #1
    CMP R2, #0
    BNE loop_r1
   ```
2. Do your strcpy like before - but reverse your usage of `R0` and `R1`.